# Javascript Multiple DateRangePicker elements on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem when I implement multiple date ranger pickers on my page. They all change text in the input field, no matter what I do it seems.

I have some "cards" made in Bootstrap. To populate the cards with data I loop over an array of people, who all get a "card" with a daterangepicker (from http://www.daterangepicker.com/#example4) in it. All cards have a daterangepicker and it's all good and dandy, but they all change their date text when a date is chosen in any of the date range input fields. I know the problem resides with me not understanding the callback function `cb` fully. I have to somehow make separate instances of the date range picker on every card.

Examples below, first one of the html cards and secondly the javascript code. How do you propose to solve this?

EDIT: *RUN CODE SNIPPET IN FULL SCREEN TO SEE EFFECT. I HAVE ROUGHLY 16 INPUTS WITH DATE RANGE ON SAME PAGE*

```js
$(function() {
  var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
  var end = moment();

  /**
   * @param {momentjs date} start 
   * @param {momentjs date} end
   * @description Function implemented from daterangepicker.com
   * @see http://www.daterangepicker.com/#example4 
   */
  function cb(start, end) {
    let vacationrange_span = $('.form-control span');
    vacationrange_span.html(start.format('DD/MM-YYYY') + ' to ' + end.format('DD/MM-YYYY'));
    vacationrange_span.attr('data-startdt', start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T00:00:00Z');
    vacationrange_span.attr('data-enddt', end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T23:59:59Z');
    vacationrange_span.attr('id', 'register-date-range');
  }

  $('[id^=vacationrange-]').each(function() {
    let idRange = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
    console.log(idRange);
    $(this).daterangepicker({
      parentEl: '#daterange-picker-' + idRange,
      showWeekNumbers: true,
      startDate: start,
      endDate: end,
      ranges: {
        'Today': [
          moment(), moment()
        ],
        'Yesterday': [
          moment().subtract(1, 'days'),
          moment().subtract(1, 'days')
        ],
        'Last 7 Days': [
          moment().subtract(6, 'days'),
          moment()
        ],
        'Last 30 Days': [
          moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
          moment()
        ],
        'This Month': [
          moment().startOf('month'),
          moment().endOf('month')
        ],
        'Last Month': [
          moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'),
          moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')
        ]
      }
    }, cb)

    cb(start, end);
  })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container col-md-9">
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 120px;">
            <h1>Vacation Registration</h1>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row row-margin-bottom">
            <div class="col-md-12 no-padding lib-item" data-category="view">
                <div class="lib-panel">
                    <div class="row box-shadow">
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <div class="lib-row lib-header">Jane Doe<div class="lib-header-seperator"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="lib-row lib-desc">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <div class="input-group" id="daterange-picker-628">
                                            <div class="form-control" style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc"
                                                id="vacationrange-628"><i class="fa fa-calendar mr-3"></i><span
                                                    class="mr-3"></span><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></div><span
                                                class="input-group-append"><button class="btn btn-success bg-klean fa fa-check"
                                                    id="vacation-import-btn-628"></button></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <p>Something something dark side</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-margin-bottom">
            <div class="col-md-12 no-padding lib-item" data-category="view">
                <div class="lib-panel">
                    <div class="row box-shadow">
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <div class="lib-row lib-header">John Doe<div class="lib-header-seperator"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="lib-row lib-desc">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <div class="input-group" id="daterange-picker-777">
                                            <div class="form-control" style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc"
                                                id="vacationrange-777"><i class="fa fa-calendar mr-3"></i><span
                                                    class="mr-3"></span><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></div><span
                                                class="input-group-append"><button class="btn btn-success bg-klean fa fa-check"
                                                    id="vacation-import-btn-777"></button></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <p>Something something dark side</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

My stylesheets imported, in order:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.3/daterangepicker.css">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/application.css">
```

My javascript scripts included and in that order, at the bottom of my html page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/application.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.3/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/vacations.js" type="module"></script>
```

Comment: Please update the [mcve] I tried to make you. There are still console errors

Comment: Done and done :) run snippet in full screen mode to see effect

Comment: ids must be unique `vacation-import-btn`

Comment: They are in my code :) I'll fix it here aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...but they all change their date text when a date is chosen in any of the date range input fields. 
>   This happens because in the **cb** callback you refer to each instance element:

```
$('.form-control span');
```

There you need to refer to the current element. In order to achieve that I'd suggest to change your callback into:

```
function cb(ele) {
    return function (start, end) {
        let vacationrange_span = $(ele).parent().find('.form-control span');
        vacationrange_span.html(start.format('DD/MM-YYYY') + ' to ' + end.format('DD/MM-YYYY'));
        vacationrange_span.attr('data-startdt', start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T00:00:00Z');
        vacationrange_span.attr('data-enddt', end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T23:59:59Z');
        vacationrange_span.attr('id', 'register-date-range');
    }
}
```

And in order to call it (in your code).....

```
, cb(this))

cb(this)(start, end);
```

```js
var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
var end = moment();

/**
 * @param {momentjs date} start
 * @param {momentjs date} end
 * @description Function implemented from daterangepicker.com
 * @see http://www.daterangepicker.com/#example4
 */
function cb(ele) {
    return function (start, end)
    {
        let vacationrange_span = $(ele).parent().find('.form-control span');
        vacationrange_span.html(start.format('DD/MM-YYYY') + ' to ' + end.format('DD/MM-YYYY'));
        vacationrange_span.attr('data-startdt', start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T00:00:00Z');
        vacationrange_span.attr('data-enddt', end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T23:59:59Z');
        vacationrange_span.attr('id', 'register-date-range');
    }
}

$('[id^=vacationrange-]').each(function() {
    let idRange = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
    //console.log(idRange);
    $(this).daterangepicker({
        parentEl: '#daterange-picker-' + idRange,
        showWeekNumbers: true,
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
            'Today': [
                moment(), moment()
            ],
            'Yesterday': [
                moment().subtract(1, 'days'),
                moment().subtract(1, 'days')
            ],
            'Last 7 Days': [
                moment().subtract(6, 'days'),
                moment()
            ],
            'Last 30 Days': [
                moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
                moment()
            ],
            'This Month': [
                moment().startOf('month'),
                moment().endOf('month')
            ],
            'Last Month': [
                moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'),
                moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')
            ]
        }
    }, cb(this))

    cb(this)(start, end);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.3/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.3/daterangepicker.css" />


 <div class="container col-md-9">
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 120px;">
            <h1>Vacation Registration</h1>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row row-margin-bottom">
            <div class="col-md-12 no-padding lib-item" data-category="view">
                <div class="lib-panel">
                    <div class="row box-shadow">
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <div class="lib-row lib-header">Jane Doe<div class="lib-header-seperator"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="lib-row lib-desc">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <div class="input-group" id="daterange-picker-628">
                                            <div class="form-control" style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc"
                                                id="vacationrange-628"><i class="fa fa-calendar mr-3"></i><span
                                                    class="mr-3"></span><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></div><span
                                                class="input-group-append"><button class="btn btn-success bg-klean fa fa-check"
                                                    id="vacation-import-btn-628"></button></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <p>Something something dark side</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-margin-bottom">
            <div class="col-md-12 no-padding lib-item" data-category="view">
                <div class="lib-panel">
                    <div class="row box-shadow">
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <div class="lib-row lib-header">John Doe<div class="lib-header-seperator"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="lib-row lib-desc">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <div class="input-group" id="daterange-picker-777">
                                            <div class="form-control" style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc"
                                                id="vacationrange-777"><i class="fa fa-calendar mr-3"></i><span
                                                    class="mr-3"></span><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></div><span
                                                class="input-group-append"><button class="btn btn-success bg-klean fa fa-check"
                                                    id="vacation-import-btn-777"></button></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <p>Something something dark side</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hmm - the weird thing here is that when I implement this into my own code, nothing happens. My vacations.js file loads, but it is never run? I never enter either the cb function or the loop. Any clues to what went wrong? Because it works in the snippet example.

Comment: Also - is there any reason that you removed the `$(function` in the top of the document?

Comment: In my code it made no difference if it's there or not. The function is never accessed and neither is the jquery each loop. I can't even get it to print a sanity check console.log from within those two. Any ideas? I'm kinda out

Comment: I will add the included scripts and their order in my question above

Comment: @IncrediblePony I'm sorry, but if it works in the snippet I don't know how to help. I added how to call the new **cb**. Try to substitute the function and the call....

Comment: Fair enough - I have added the scripts I import in my original question. I will try to get it to work somehow. Thanks for your help

Comment: Setting this as accepted answer :) I'm sure you are correct, but it's just me that's stupid :)